# What steps can be taken to recover from rm -rf ~

Tags: macos, command-line

Asking for a friend.

Imagine that one has accidentally created a file named `~` and in the process of deleting it, foolishly types:

```
rm -rf ~
```

Luckily, I have active terminal windows open, so all is not entirely lost. I happened to have stopped this while it was deleting in the `~/.` prefixed directories, too, so I somehow have all my work related content still as those directories didn't get hit with the `rm` (lucky, I know).

Is there any way to recover from this? What files do I need to recreate while I still have valid terminal sessions?

I'm under the assumption that all my configuration (mostly in `~/.` named folders/directories) is permanently gone. I've recovered some of my .bash_profile by looking at `env`, `alias`, and `typeset -f` but I'm sure I'm missing parts of it.

Comment: You need to sacrifice a rubber chicken at the alter of Time Machine.  Short of that, you can try a recovery utility like [DiskDrill](http://cleveryfiles.com) but this is not guaranteed.  The more you use the drive, the less your chances of recovery.

Comment: @Allan my friend says that he doesn't use Time Machine... ;_;

Comment: It's time for a new profile and a lesson in the virtues of backup.

Comment: We need a **close the question** item: "Please restore ... from TM backup."

Comment: @Allan yeah, turns out my work doesn't auto backup anything (rough way for me to find that out). The plan is to reimage everything tomorrow and start from scratch, but I'd like to be able to recover as much as I can prior to that.

Comment: @klanomath http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2927/restore-from-backup

Comment: You should use ls -l to try out a riskie command before you try rm.  And using, -r is crazy. It is recursive delete.  -f.  I would have cd'd to the problem directory and done a ls -l '~' and seen what you got.  Then rm '~'.  Also, delete things from the finder.

Comment: You can get hidden files to show up in the finder.  TRUE to show and FALSE to hide.  See next comment.

Comment: defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE   ;killall Finder

Answer (score 1):

`rm` is one of those dangerous commands where to "Err is human, but to really foul things up, you need a computer."  `rm` immediately deletes the files and bypasses the Trash...you don't pass "Go" and you don't "collect $200."

Your best bet is to....

1. Stop using the machine as in **ASAP.**  The more your use it, the more disk activity, the less of a chance of recovery.
2. Look at getting something like [DiskDrill](https://www.cleverfiles.com/).  It's free to use but the actual recovery will cost around $100.  There are others, but I found this one works really well for me.
3. Start a Time Machine regimen and adhere to it.

Comment: Oh, as a software developer I know the danger of `rm`. My problem was naively trying to delete `~/.mypath/~` with it..

Comment: Been there.  TM is good, but I created a differencing script that copies my work to the Cloud and to a local NAS and keeps 7 days worth of variations.  If I hose things up, I have at minimum two places to get back to.

Comment: @enderland: Next time you want to delete a directory with a risky name, first type `echo risky_name`. For example `echo 2 * hotels` to see how to use it correctly (here `rm -rf './2 * hotels'`).

Comment: @danielAzuelos "Ctrl-x" followed by "*" does wildcard expansion; but I'm not sure what happens with the tilde. Hard to test on my phone...

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that only files/folder starting with a dot are gone you are actually quite safe. Hardly anything on macOS relies on such files. If you want to recover the defaults, create a new user account and copy any missing stuff from there.

The key issues probably come from the init files of your shell and your ssh configuration. I would assume/hope that you know haw to rebuild them if you are experienced enough to change/use them :-)

PS: it would also be a good opportunity to establish a backup strategy...

Comment: `If you are sure` Sure? No. Optimistic though? Yeah.